# Function preserving convergence between metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between metric spaces $X, Y$ which preserves convergent sequences. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

So this is a variation of the typical question that if a function between metric spaces preserves convergent sequences AND their limits, then it is continuous. So this amounts to showing that if $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ then $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$.

There seems to be an obvious and straightforward solution to this, but at the moment I can't think of it. I would be interested to hear something more elegant. Also would like to know if my solution is correct, even though it's not very elegant.

**SOLUTION:** Recall that a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for any $A \subseteq X$, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

So let $A \subseteq X$ be arbitrary. Let $x \in \overline{A}$. Since $X$ is a metric space (and therefore first countable), we can extract a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. Then by hypothesis, $\{f(x_{n})\}$ converges.

Let $K_{x} = \{x_{n}\} \cup \{x\}$. Notice this is a closed set. Then consider $f(K_{x}) = f(\overline{K_{x}})$. If $f(K_{x})$ is closed $f(\overline{K_{x}}) = \overline{f(K_{x}})$. In this case, it contains its limit, say $y$.

If $f(K_{x})$ is not closed, then $\overline{f(K_{x}}) = f(K_{x}) \cup \{y\}$ will give, and we certainly have that $f(\overline{K_{x}}) \subseteq \overline{f(K_{x}})$.

Then it follows that $f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, if we just write $\overline{A} = \displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in \overline{A}} K_{x}$, for any $A \subseteq X$.

Comment: See also: [A map between metric spaces preserving convergent sequences is continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740880/a-map-between-metric-spaces-preserving-convergent-sequences-is-continuous)