# Is there any name for this family of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Phi$ be the class of all fonctions  $\phi$ (let's say from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$) such that:

**For each sequence $\{t_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ that converges, the sequence $\{\phi(t_n)\}$ converges also.**

- Is there any specific name for this class of functions?
- It will be interesting to see some interesting examples/counterexamples.

Comment: Continuous function !

Comment: Yeah the class of continuous functions is a subclass of  $\Phi$, but I'm looking for something more general, I mean even if $x_n\rightarrow x$, I want $\phi (x_n)$ to converge, but **not necessarily** to $\phi(x)$.

Comment: @Martin R: in the Q&A that you referred to, the OP imposed $f(x_0) $ as a limite of $f(x_n)$.

Comment: @Motaka: You are right. I was misled by the title. But see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1740880.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tiny gap between the stated condition and the standard definition of a continuous function, but that gap can be filled as follows: if $\{ t_n\}$ converges to $a$, consider the sequence $\{s_n\}$ with terms $t_1, a, t_2, a, t_3, a, \ldots $. Then $\{ s_n\}$ converges (to $a$) and the convergence of $\{ f(s_n) \}$ implies that $\{f(t_n)\}$ converges to $f(a)$.

Comment: Precisely: that's the gap. The convergence of the sequence $f(t_1), f(a), f(t_2), f(a), ... $ implies that $f(t_n)$ converges to $f(a)$.

Comment: Your answer seems right, but still my intuition tells me  that the class $\Phi$ is bigger than the class of continuous functions. Take $\phi$ equal zero in $\mathbb{R}^+-\{1\}$, and $\phi(1)=1$.

Comment: @Motaka: consider the convergent sequence $1, 3/2, 1, 4/3, 1, 5/4, 1, 6/5, ... $. The sequence $\phi(1), \phi(3/2), \phi(1), \phi(4/3) ... $ is then $1,0,1, 0, 1, 0, ... $ and is not converging.