# Specific family of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Phi$ be the class of all fonctions  $\phi$ (let's say from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$) such that:

If there exist an **increasing sequences (not necessarily strictly)**  $\{t_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ that converges, then the sequence $\{\phi(t_n)\}$ converges also.

- Is there any specific name for this class of functions?
- It will be interesting to see some interesting examples/counterexamples.

---

See similar discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740880/a-map-between-metric-spaces-preserving-convergent-sequences-is-continuous) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.515.9204&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi \in \Phi$ if and only if

1. $f$ has left limits at all points,  i.e. $\lim_{s<t, s \to t} f(s) $ exists and
2. $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)$ exists.

[The limit in 1) need not be $f(t)$ so $f$ need not be left continuous].

All monotone bounded functions have these properties.

Comment: Great. 1)Could you suggest any name for this class  to refer to? In the second reference above  they use weakly continuous (which may create a confusion in the weak toplogy). 2) In 1. $s\leq t$ instead of $s<t$, No?

Comment: Limit of $f(s)$ with $s=t$ does not put any restriction on $f$. So limit with $s<t$ is correct. We can call these functions as functions with left limits in $(-\infty, \infty]$. There is no continuity of any kind involved. @Motaka